# Solve $\lim_{x\to0} \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

We know that to find limit at $x=0$, function must be defined in neighborhood of $x=0$

Let's see if function is defined in left neighborhood of $x=0$

$l=0-\delta$ will be the left neighborhood of $x=0$ where $\delta$ is very very$\cdots\cdots$ small positive number.

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{(0-\delta)^2}$$
$$\tan^{-1}(+\infty)$$

As we know $\tan^{-1}$ is not defined at $+\infty$, so it means at left neighborhood function is not defined.

Let's see if function is defined in right neighborhood of $x=0$

$r=0+\delta$ will be the right neighborhood of $x=0$.

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{(0+\delta)^2}$$
$$\tan^{-1}(+\infty)$$

As we know $\tan^{-1}$ is not defined at +$\infty$, so it means at right neighborhood also function is not defined.

But actual answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ which is not difficult to find why but it breaks the basic principle of limits right? What am I missing here?

Comment: What makes you think that $\arctan$ is not defined in a neighbourhood of $+\infty$? It most certainly is.

Comment: tell me one think , is $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ defined at $0^{+}$. Or in other terms is $\tan^{-1}x$ defined at $x=+\infty$?

Comment: $\arctan\frac1{x^2}$ is defined on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: The function does not have to be defined at a point for a limit to exists.

Comment: bro I am talking about neighborhood here, $0^{+}$ is a right neighborhood of $x=0$

Comment: why I got a downvote here?

Comment: @prat most likely because you are being argumentative with people trying to help you. Graph $\arctan(x)$ to see its behavior as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @NinadMunshi, is function $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ defined at $0^{+}$? Yes or no? where $0^{+}$ is the right neighborhood of $x=0$

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you want since you seem to be using $0^+$ to interchangeably mean both the point and the neighborhood to the right of the point, but I'll be as clear as I can so you can understand. That function is most certainly well defined for every $x\neq 0$. It is undefined exactly at $x=0$, but a function does not have to be defined at a point for its limit to exist, as Dayton already pointed out. These are called holes.

Comment: ok, but just tell me one thing what is $\dfrac{1}{0^{+}}$ , is it $+\infty$? By $0^{+}$ i mean very very very$\cdots\cdots$ small positive number

Comment: See, this is the problem again. Earlier you wanted $0^+$ to be a neighborhood, but now you are treating it like a point. There is nothing wrong with having your own, well defined, sensible notation, but do not ever flip between meanings so casually. This is the source of frustration between you and the other answerers. Lesson here is do not be lazy and use math as a replacement for sentences. Write everything in as clear a english as possible with as few symbols as necessary.

Comment: see I still consider $0^{+}$ as the neighborhood point, what is wrong in this, tell me? I am just asking whether $tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is defined at this neighborhood point

Comment: That makes zero sense. There is no such thing as a "neighborhood point". A neighborhood is a collection of points.

Comment: ok , thats well said, I go by your definition, $0^{+}$ is a collection of points very close to $0$. Now tell me if there is any point from this set where $tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ can be defined. 

I think there is no point in this set for which $tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is defined as for every point in this set, $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ will be $+\infty$

Comment: @prat of course $1/x^2$ it is defined for any $x\neq 0$ or as you would like any "very small" number $x$. As already given in the answer by user the limit as $x$ tends to zero is $+\infty$ and so the composition $\tan^{-1}(1/x^2)$ tends to $\pi/2$. The function is perfectly defined for ANY non-zero number.

Comment: I have already answered this question in my second comment. Now that you are on the same page as everybody else, re read theirs and my comments.

Comment: I think my only confusion left is this, $0^{+}$ is a collection of points very close to $0$. Is there any point in this set where $tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is defined.

I think there is no point in this set because  if you take out any point from this set and calculate $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, it will be $+\infty$ and $tan^{-1}$ is not defined at $+\infty$. Please given your final answer for this.

Comment: I think I have made myself very crystal clear.

Comment: @prat: I have added an answer which deals with your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$f(x) =\dfrac{1}{x^2} \to \infty$$

and then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\arctan (f(x)) =\lim_{f(x)\to \infty}\arctan (f(x)) = \frac \pi 2$$

Comment: My only confusion left is this, $0^{+}$ is a right neighborhood of $x=0$  where $0^{+}$ is a collection of points very close to $0$. Is there any point in this collection where $tan^{−1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is defined. I think there is no point in this collection because if you take out any point from this set and calculate $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, it will be $+\infty$ and $tan^{−1}$ is not defined at $+\infty$

Comment: We have that $1/x^2$ becomes bigger and bigger as $x$ tends to zero but it is not correct say that $1/x^2$ is equal to $\infty$, we say that its limit is $infty$ which is a different concept.You should revise the definition of limit. You can prove rigoursly the result by that.

Answer (score 1):

You had better get a clear idea of the term *neighborhood* which seems to be primary source of confusion (as indicated by your comments).

A *neighborhood* of a point $c$ is an open interval containing $c$. Thus $(1,3), (1,2.001)$ are both neighborhoods of point $2$. In your comments you have developed a notation for *right neighborhood* and its definition should be $$c^{+} =I_c\cap\{x\mid x\in\mathbb {R}, x>c\} $$ where $I_c$ is any neighborhood of $c$. Thus a right neighborhood of $c$ is a neighborhood with all points less than or equal to $c$ removed from it. By the very nature of this definition your notation $c^{+} $ does not represent any one specific set but rather can be used to represent any right neighborhood.

It should be also be observed that $c^{+} $ is always of the form $(c, d) $ or $(c, \infty) $.

The key point is that $c\notin c^{+} $ and thus if $x\in 0^{+}$ then $x\neq 0$ and hence $1/x^2$ is well defined and consequently $\tan^{-1}(1/x^2)$ is well defined.

---

Another typical problem is the use of the term "very small number" (repeat the word very as many times as you wish to increase its intensity or effect). The phrase is meaningless without any additional context. A number is smaller compared to another number.

In typical daily life real world scnearios we know the context and can use the phrase "very small" accordingly.

In the context of real numbers there is no number which is very small. There is always a smaller one. This is an intuitive fact but somehow people learning calculus don't seem to appreciate it. And often one desperately desires the existence of a very very small positive number. This line of thinking has to be ditched seriously.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{\text{Hint:}}$

Since $1/x^2\gt 0$ hence $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$\lim_{x\to 0}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=
\lim_{x\to 0}\cot^{-1}\left(x^2\right)$$

Where, $\cot^{-1}\theta\in(0, \pi)\quad \forall \ \theta\in(-\infty, \infty)$